# Background images not appearing on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://hamzicabdulah.github.io/personal-portfolio/

Everything works just fine on any browser when I open the page on my PC/laptop — the page is responsive, all the background images appear on any screen size... But, when I open the page on my mobile phone, the background images for the first two section do not appear. I don't know how to fix this issue. I've tried removing the following code for mobile size:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

... But that didn't change anything at all. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the largest image size that the iOS browser display without downsampling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935785/whats-the-largest-image-size-that-the-ios-browser-display-without-downsampling) even though the actual question is not worded the same - look at the linked question for answers.

Comment: That really doesn't help with my issue...

Comment: Works fine on mine I would shrink down the images they are way to big now

Comment: The linked question explains how to calculate what the biggest size size image is that will be supported on your device and why - this is your issue - the image is too large and won't render on older devices running iOS.

Comment: But... My body background image has the dimensions of 852 x 480. That means I shouldn't experience this problem. And also, I'm using an Android device. :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so basically, I figured the answer myself, so I'll post it here, so that anyone with a similar problem can find this helpful. I actually just figured out that linear-gradient obviously can't work on certain mobile devices and therefore using css code like this one...

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('http://www.inmeteo.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/toscana.jpg') center;
```

... for mobile view makes the background image invisible on some devices (like for example, my Samsung Galaxy S3). Therefore, I just removed the linear-gradient for mobile view and it works fine now...